# How to pipe the os.Stdout to a golang template

Tags: templates, go, exec, stdout

I was wondering if there was a way to pass the contents of exec.Command a template file in golang. My template file is static.  Currently, I use code that looks like this

```
cmd = exec.Command("/bin/sh", shellScript)
cmd.Stdout = os.Stdout
cmd.Stderr = os.Stderr
cmd.Run()
```

which works great if I want to view the server shell to see output from running that shell script..  Now i want to take it a step further and push the output of that shell script to my index.html.  I could store the contents of the process in a string and pass it in... but i was thinking something more real time.  Any ideas, etc?

Comment: What do you mean "more real time"? Have you tried [`Output`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/#Cmd.Output) and [`CombinedOutput`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/#Cmd.CombinedOutput)?

Comment: I mean if I store the contents as a string and send the input, the user gets all the output at the same time, not as the content is being generated. Another way to put it. I want to pipe the stdout to the template as I'm receiving it. Not after the system call is done.

Comment: That's not really what templating is for. If you want to pipe the output you could write a header template, pipe the output, then a trailer template. It would be much easier though if the client requested the stream separately from the template and handled the display on the client side. This way the template is properly validated, not to mention clients may not display (or can't display) the html until it's complete, so there's no point in "streaming" a large chunk of it.

Comment: Why not using tcp socket streaming ? https://github.com/StabbyCutyou/buffstreams

Comment: That's a good idea. I'll read the link you sent me. I was thinking of using channels as well.